# AngularJS model is populated in javascript but empty on the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I've got this code...**

```
Agencyapp.factory('AgencyData', function ($http, $log) {
return {
    getAgencies: function(successcb){
        $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost/MappingServicesWebAPI/api/mapping' }).
        success(function(data){
            successcb(data);
        }).
        error(function(data){
            $log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
        })
    }

}
});
```

Which gets data from a WebAPI.  The `$scope.Agencies` model gets populated with an `AgencyList` array. When I try to use that array...

```
<div ng-controller="AgenciesCtrl">
    <select ng-model="Agencies">
        <option>Select Agency</option>
        <option ng-repeat="A in Agencies" >{{A.AgencyList.AgencyName}}</option>
    </select>
    {{Agencies.AgencyList}}
</div>
```

It's empty...can someone help me with what I might be doing wrong?

Here's the controller, sorry I thought I included it...

```
Agencyapp.controller('AgenciesCtrl', function AgenciesCtrl($scope, AgencyData) {

AgencyData.getAgencies().then(function (rtnAgencies) {
    $scope.Agencies = rtnAgencies;

});
```

});

I tried to post a picture of the populated $scope object but I don't have enough reputation points...

It Looks like this(each indent is a nested object)...

```
$scope.Agencies
  [prototype]
  AgencyList[]
    [0]
      [prototype]
      AgencyID    -10168
      AgencyName  "#1 Insurance Agency"
```

**If I hard code data...**

```
function AgenciesCtrl($scope, AgencyData) {

$scope.Agencies = [
            {
                AgencyID: 'Test One',
                AgencyName: 'Agency Test 1'
            },
            {
                AgencyID: 'Test Two',
                AgencyName: 'Agency Test 2'
            }];


};
```

**It Works**

**If I hard code data inside the function call**

```
function AgenciesCtrl($scope, AgencyData) {



AgencyData.getAgencies().then(function (rtnAgencies) {
    $scope.Agencies = [
            {
                AgencyID: 'Test One',
                AgencyName: 'Agency Test 1'
            },
            {
                AgencyID: 'Test Two',
                AgencyName: 'Agency Test 2'
            }];


});


};
```

**It doesn't work**

I haven't seen one good example of using data from a web api...all examples I have seen hard code data, what's the point in that?

Comment: Can you post your controller? It may be that a `$digest` cycle never kicked off.

Comment: I suppose you handle data passed to `successcb` wrong, but I can't say anything without controller.

Comment: **Anyone have any ideas for me?**

Comment: Any ideas...how do you get a question answered on this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had my...

```
<div ng-controller="AgenciesCtrl">
<select ng-model="Agencies">
    <option>Select Agency</option>
    <option ng-repeat="A in Agencies" >{{A.AgencyList.AgencyName}}</option>
</select>
{{Agencies.AgencyList}}
</div>
```

Inside a  that was controlled by a Javascript Library called Slidebox.js.
Once I removed Slidebox.js everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove `ng-model="Agencies"` from your `<select>` element.  You dont want to bind your select element to the same object that you are running an `ng-repeat` on.  Try something like `<select ng-model="selectedAgency" >` instead.

Second, I suggest utilizing angular's deferred API to return a promise, which will then be resolved with the value of the data returned from the server, when it is finished:

```
Agencyapp.factory('AgencyData', function ($http, $log, $q) {
return {
    getAgencies: function(successcb){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost/MappingServicesWebAPI/api/mapping' }).
        success(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(successcb(data)); //I dont know what successcb() does                
        }).
        error(function(data){
            deferred.reject(data);
            $log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
        })
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
});
```

In your controller, you would then do something like this:

```
  AgencyData.getAgencies().then(function(data) {
     $scope.Agencies = data;
  });
```

As soon as the getAgencies() function finishes getting the data, the $scope.Agencies object will be updated with the resulting data.

Comment: Thanks for the response...I have implemented the changes you suggested but get the same result a populated $scope object that doesn't seem to carry back to the page.

Comment: **Anybody have any ideas for me?**

Comment: what does successcb do? have you been able to confirm through firebug that the data is indeed being successfully returned in the format you are expecting?  What format is the data being returned in, can you provide a screenshot or sample of what the actual returned data looks like?

Comment: I provided that by editing my original post...I tried to post a picture but I don't have enough reputation points.  I took the cbSuccess function out and I get the same results...it was just a call back function.

Comment: Any ideas...how do you get a question answered on this site?